# AngularJS ng-minlength ng-required not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I want to set Validation for input like minimum length is 5 and maximum length is 6.

I have to **set 5 to 6 Digits only** into my textbox.

For this I am using below code but it is not working

```
<div class="input-wrap lg-input">
    <input type="text" name="num" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits" ng-minlength="5" maxlength="6"
        ng-model="profInfo.Number" ng-required="true">
    <div class="error" ng-show="profInfoForm.$submitted || profInfoForm.num.$touched">
        <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.required">Required Field</span>
        <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.minlength">Invalid input</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button-ctr">
    <button class="button" ng-class="profInfoForm.$valid ? 'active' : 'disable'">Next</button>
</div>
```

**Currently this is working like below:**

When textbox is empty and I clicked on Next button it showing Required Field error message that is correct.

I cannot type more than 6 digits that is correct.

When I type 1 digit into textbox and clicked on button it showing Required Field error message that is wrong.

When I type 5th digits it showing Invalid input error message that is wrong.

I am using AngularJS v1.5.5.

Comment: Can you explain "it is not working" part? What do you expect, and how it actually behaves?

Comment: Why do you use maxlength in favour of ng-maxlength?

Comment: @DevDig I want that user cannot type input greater than 6 digits.

Comment: @user3441151 It won't stop your user from typing more than 6 digits, it will just set a validation error

Comment: @GermanRumm I just update my question, Please check again.

Comment: @NexusDuck But using maxlength="6" I cannot typed more than 6 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `ng-show="profInfoForm.$submitted || profInfoForm.num.$touched"` to `ng-show="(profInfoForm.num.$dirty || submitted)"`

```
<input type="text" name="num" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits" minlength="5" maxlength="6" ng-model="profInfo.Number" ng-required="true">
    <div class="error" ng-show="(profInfoForm.num.$dirty || submitted)">
      <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.required">Required Field</span>
      <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.minlength">Invalid input</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Have a look at [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/cFx8r1BxZbjRjRJSfjoU?p=preview)

Comment: @NagaveerGowda I am not saying your demo is not working. When I applied your code into my code than it's not working.

Comment: @user3441151In the demo, I have used your code only. put your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Try out this -

```
<input type="text" name="num" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="6" ng-model="profInfo.Number" required>
    <div class="error" role="alert">
       <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.required">Required Field</span>
       <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.minlength">Too Short!</span>
       <span ng-show="profInfoForm.num.$error.maxlength">Too Long!</span>
    </div>
```

**2)** But I will prefer this below solution for angular form validations.

```
<form role="form" name="FORMNAME" ng-submit="vm.submitForm(formData)" novalidate>        
  <div class="form-group form-md-line-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : FORMNAME.num.$invalid && !FORMNAME.num.$pristine}">
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Number <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num" ng-model="formData.number" placeholder="Enter 5-6 digits" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="6" required>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="FORMNAME.num.$error.required">Please enter name</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="FORMNAME.num.$error.minlength">Too Short!</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="FORMNAME.num.$error.maxlength">Too Long!</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Use bootstrap "has-error" class and with this your element will turn into red if any validation fails, "has-error" class works with control-label, form-control classes.

"novalidate" will block chrome html5 validations.